# I have a WIX website and I am trying to use the 'Accept Hosted' api from Authorize.net but I am stuck trying to redirect to the payment page

Tags: javascript, velo

I am able to get the token from 'getHostedPaymentPageRequest' using fetch. Now I am stumped at trying to redirect to the authorize.net payment page. I have tried the following in the front end:

```
        const payUrl = 'https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment?token=' + objToken.token;
        console.log("payUrl: " + payUrl);
        try {
            wixLocation.to(payUrl);
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

I get no response and no error is trapped.
In the backend I have tried several things such as:
Authorize.net's HTML example which fails because WIX/javascript does not like raw HTML pasted into a function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" id="formAuthorizeNetTestPage" name="formAuthorizeNetTestPage">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value=token />
    Continue to Authorize.Net to Payment Page
    <button id="btnContinue">Continue to next page</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried fetch which I did not think would work because I am trying to redirect not retrieve. The following returns 'Successful" but of course no redirect happens.

```
const url = 'https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment';

return fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, 
    body: JSON.stringify(token)
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Authorize.net has a PHP example program using CURL but nothing I can use in WIX/javascript.
I feel like this shouldn't be that hard but you don't know what you don't know. 
Any help would be appreciated.